# Why DynamoDB java sdk doesn't allow always auto-generated keys?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to implement change history for my objects in DynamoDB. Easy way of doing it would be to specify "object id" as hash and "updated time" as range key. However, java sdk doesn't allow annotating keys to be always autogenerated (changing the value without annotation convenience seems to work). Why?

Example code:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "data")
public class Person {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient()
                .withEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

        TableUtils.deleteTableIfExists(client, mapper.generateDeleteTableRequest(Person.class));
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(client, mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(Person.class)
                .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L))
        );

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setPersonId("abc");

        mapper.save(person);
        mapper.save(person);

        TableUtils.deleteTableIfExists(client, mapper.generateDeleteTableRequest(Person.class));
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String personId;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp
    private Long updated;

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public Long getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Long updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Field com.dynamodb.testpackage.Person[updated] must not have auto-generated key with ALWAYS strategy
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel$Builder.build(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:797)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$SchemaFactory.newTableModel(StandardModelFactories.java:118)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$SchemaFactory.getTableModel(StandardModelFactories.java:86)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.getTableModel(DynamoDBMapper.java:401)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:2432)
    at com.dynamodb.testpackage.Person.main(Person.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use-case is atypical. Usually you don't want the hash and range key of an object to change. In fact I would go as far as to say it's discouraged.

In fact, with DynamoDB an item is uniquely characterized by it's key (whether partition key only, or partition + range keys together) so changing the range key essentially creates a new item which is technically not an update.

I'm not sure if this accurately represents *the* reason why mixing `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp` and `@DynamoDBRangeKey` is not supported in the SDK but it's certainly a reason.